# how to pass java script prompt msg variable value in to php?

Tags: javascript, php, alert

how to pass java script prompt msg variable value in to php.

```
<?php 
  echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
        var msg = window.prompt("Input a value", ""); alert(msg);
        </script>';    
   //then need to use input value to php    
   echo $value; //how to get JS value to here?
 ?>
```

or is there any other way to get php prompt massages to input value?

Comment: You need to use AJAX for pass data from javascript to PHP

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do it directly like this. You need to pass the value from javascript to PHP. One easy way of doing so would be using redirect:

```
<?php 
  echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
        var value = prompt("Input a value", "");
        window.location.href = '?value='+encodeURIComponent(value);
        </script>';    
   //then need to use input value to php    
  if (isset($_GET['value'])) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($value);
  }
 ?>
```

Even though this is very simple example based upon your code, there are more advanced ways of achieving your goal. But this is to get you going.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that as `php` is a server side language, it is interpreted before any javascript.

What you need is using `AJAX`, or using a `form`.

Both can do the work, the difference is that with `Ajax` you won't have to reload the page (nor load any other).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
echo "<script>var email=prompt('Enter user mail')</script>";

$email="<script>document.write(email)</script>";
```